# Having an erro when executing flutter run

Tags: flutter, dart

Im stuck at this problem for a week, can anyone explain to me why i cant run a flutter app either vscode or android studio. I already install all the requirements such as: sdk,ndk,emulator but i still got this problem

-

- [  +23 ms] executing:
  [C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Flutter\hello_world\android/]
  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Flutter\hello_world\android\gradlew.bat
  -Pverbose=true    -Ptarget-platform=android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 -Ptarget=lib\main.dart    -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=true bundleRelease [+12053 ms] Observed package id    'system-images;android-28;google_ndk_playstore;x86' in inconsistent
  location
  'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86'
  (Expected
  'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-28\google_ndk_playstore\x86')
  [+1115 ms] IOException:
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-3.xml [   +6 ms]
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect [+1226 ms]
  IOException:
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml [   +5 ms]
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect [+1166 ms]

Comment: Share your `flutter doctor` output, and perhaps you can explain more about your app, is it the default hello world one?

Comment: Try run the studio as admin.

Comment: Everthings fine when i run flutter doctor -v

Comment: Im using vscode to run this. I tried android studio but it also gave same errors

Comment: I tried googling this error

Comment: [+106953 ms] Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_ndk_playstore;x86' in inconsistent location'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86' (Expected
'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-28\google_ndk_playstore\x86')
[+1405 ms] Observed package id 'system-images;android-28;google_ndk_playstore;x86' in inconsistent location
'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86' (Expected
'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-28\google_ndk_playstore

Comment: But i cant find someone similar as mine